# jQuery current menu code optimization

Tags: jquery, href

I have below code written in jQuery:

```
var href = window.location.href;
if (href.search('/welcome\\/') > 0)
{
    $('.menuwelcome').css('display', 'block');
    $('#welcome2').append('<b>Приглашаем субагентов</b>').find('a').remove();
    $('#welcome2').find('img').attr('src', '/static/images/arrow_black.gif');
}
if (href.search('/contacts\\/') > 0)
{
    $('.menuwelcome').css('display', 'block');
    $('#mcontacts').append('<b>Контакты</b>').find('a').remove();
    $('#mcontacts').find('img').attr('src', '/static/images/arrow_black_down.gif');
}
if (href.search('/sindbad_history\\/') > 0)
{
    $('.menuwelcome').css('display', 'block');
    $('.menuwelcome:first').append('<b>История</b>').find('a').remove();
    $('.menuwelcome:first').find('img').attr('src', '/static/images/arrow_black.gif');
}
if (href.search('/insurance\\/') > 0)
{
    $('.menusafe').css('display', 'block');
    $('#msafe').append('<b>Страхование</b>').find('a').remove();
    $('#msafe').find('img').attr('src', '/static/images/arrow_black_down.gif');
}
if (href.search('/insurance_advices\\/') > 0)
{
    $('.menusafe').css('display', 'block');
    $('.menusafe:first').append('<b>Полезная информация</b>').find('a').remove();
    $('.menusafe:first').find('img').attr('src', '/static/images/arrow_black.gif');
}
```

The code above have repetitive task, Can we make the code compact?
I want to minimize this code. How should I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML for the menu?

Comment: Minimizing code is not relevant on StackOverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place all the variable bits in a dictionary of arrays:

```
cases = {
    '/welcome\\/' : ['.menuwelcome', '#welcome2' , 'Приглашаем субагентов', 'arrow_black.gif'     ],
    '/contacts\\/': ['.menuwelcome', '#mcontacts', 'Контакты'             , 'arrow_black_down.gif'],
    ...
};
```

Then loop over the cases:

```
for (c in cases) {
    if (href.search(c)) {
        a = cases[c];
        $(a[0]).css('display', 'block'); 
        $(a[1]).append('<b>' + a[2] + '</b>').find('a').remove(); 
        $(a[1]).find('img').attr('src', '/static/images/' + a[3]); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Great idea.  Note that the image url is different in the various cases as well.  Probably want to `break` out of the loop once you've found a match as well.

Comment: Thank you, @tvanfosson. I missed the variation in the images. Amended.

Answer (score 0):

If the link that you are removing contains the same text that you are inserting, which I suspect is the case, you could use [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) instead of keeping track of it.  This would make it more resilent to changes in the text.  I'd also prefer using a class to change the font style for the "current" menu item.  Keying off @Marcelo's solution:

```
   $(a[1]).find('a').unwrap().addClass('current-menu-item');
```